# Python; Instagram API, get user feed

Tags: python, django, api, instagram, instagram-api

There are several similar questions but they all either have outdated answers or were left unanswered.

I am trying to use the instagram API to get a user's feed, but this the only related API call I can find is:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

and this only returns posts from the user. Is it still possible to do this (after the user is authenticated, of course)? Any help would be greatly appreciated, even a simple yes or no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of the API endpoint says:

> Get the most recent media published by the owner of the access_token.

See https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

What you want to do was possible with the endpoint `/users/self/feed`, but this has been deprecated in November 2015, see https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

I'm afraid the short answer is no.

Comment: Simple, concise. Great answer. Thank you very much.